# Most efficient way to query joined tables in Filemaker Pro 10

Tags: filemaker

I am tasked with extracting data from 2 tables: Master and Charges. The common key is two alpha fields.

I need to filter the results by fields in each of the two tables-- Year and Office in the Master, and another alpha field in the Charges.

There are over a million master records, and about 4 charges for each on average.

The tables have come from a legacy system and are presently in Filemaker Pro Advanced version 10.

Once the filters are in place, I intend to export the data and further summarize the results in Excel, since I'm more familiar with that.

What is the most efficient way to join and filter this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a relationship between the 2 tables, then do a find operation in the charges table.  Be sure to allow indexing on the fields you're searching on, FileMaker should be able to do a relatively speedy search over the 4 million records if the fields are indexed.

Comment: Does it matter where I define the relationship -- in the Master or Charges table?